# How do I create a DB2 database if my user account does not have the authority?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, db2, windows-server-2008, maximo

I am installing Maximo 7.5 Admin Workstation. I am on part 3 of 3, where I am installing the Maximo Asset Management. I am using my Windows domain account that has local Administrator rights.

This is the error I see on the screen:

[image]

When I review the CTGInstallTrace00.log , the relevant part is:

> C:\Windows\Temp>"C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin\db2" create db 'maxdb75'
>   ALIAS 'maxdb75' using codeset UTF-8 territory US pagesize 32 K
>
> SQL1092N  "MYUSERACCT" does not have the authority to perform the 
>   requested command or operation.

What I have tried:

- I tried to assign DBADM privilege to a Windows domain user account using DB2 command line? Logged in as the domain user with Administrators role, I went to Start > IBM DB2 > DB2COPY1 (Default) > Command Line Tools > Command Windows - Administrator. I tried to run `db2 grant DBADM to MYUSERACCT` -- I just get returned back to the command prompt.
- I also tried logging in as local\db2admin and trying to grant DBADM privilege to the domain account. I don't know if I got the syntax wrong, or something else is not done correctly. If I type `db2 grant DBADM to user MYUSERACCT` then I get this error:

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it 
>   returned:   SQL1024N A database connection does not exists.
>   SQLSTATE=08003

This article explains the [SQL1024N](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01092n.html?locale=en) error somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this error later on in the installation, the Maximo 7.5 installation should be performed using a local account with Administrators role. Domain User with Administrator role may cause issues depending on what the policies are on the Domain.

You will know there is an issue with rights, if you are unable to "Verify Installation Requirements" successfully (part 1 of 3)

Although the middleware installation may run smoothly (part 2 of 3), the Maximo Asset Management install (part 3 of 3) may fail with the DB2 database creation error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only grant the DBADM privilege on an existing database, and you must be connected to that database to issue the GRANT SQL statement, obviously.

If you took time to check [the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-21&lang=en), you'd know that the user needs SYSADM or SYSCTRL authority to create a database. These authorities are granted to members of the group specified in the `SYSADM_GROUP` or `SYSCTRL_GROUP` instance configuration parameters.

Comment: I'm not a db2 dba. How do I give sysadm or sysctrl authority to myuseracct then?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005380.html?lang=en

Comment: Interesting, I already have local administrator role as a domain user.  I would think then I should already have sysadm privileges? Perhaps group policies as a domain user is overriding some policies I would otherwise need and bypass logged in with a local administrator account...